# Group by at user level and encode categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, group-by, pivot

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
user    ID   cat1   cat2   views
12345   1      A      B     1 
67890   2      D      F     1
12345   2      D      F     1
34567   3      E      F     2 
67890   3      E      F     1
```

and so on.

Basically, each ID has a unique number of category/tags. So if you see, ID 2 and 3 for users have the same tags when viewed.

I want to convert this into:

```
user   cat1_A cat1_D cat1E....   cat2_B cat2_F.....
12345    1      1      0             1     1
67890    0      1      1             0     2
34567    0      0      2             0     2
```

and so on.

Basically encode the categories with the views they had. Kindly help.

Comment: Good catch! I rectified it. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only think of split it with for loop do it one by one with `pivot` then `concat`

```
l = ['cat1', 'cat2']
s = pd.concat([df.pivot_table(index='user', columns=x, values='views',aggfunc='first') for x in l], axis=1, keys=l).fillna(0)
s.columns=s.columns.map('_'.join)
s
Out[392]: 
       cat1_A  cat1_D  cat1_E  cat2_B  cat2_F
user                                         
12345     1.0     1.0     0.0     1.0     1.0
34567     0.0     0.0     2.0     0.0     2.0
67890     0.0     1.0     1.0     0.0     1.0
```

Comment: Yes, that did work. I am going to put this as answer for the time being. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

IIUC:

```
d = df.set_index('user')[['cat1', 'cat2']].stack().str.get_dummies().sum(level=[0, 1])
d

            A  B  D  E  F
user                     
12345 cat1  1  0  1  0  0
      cat2  0  1  0  0  1
67890 cat1  0  0  1  1  0
      cat2  0  0  0  0  2
34567 cat1  0  0  0  1  0
      cat2  0  0  0  0  1
```

then housekeeping

```
d.unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1).loc[:, lambda x: x.gt(0).any()]

      cat1       cat2   
         A  D  E    B  F
user                    
12345    1  1  0    1  1
34567    0  0  1    0  1
67890    0  1  1    0  2
```

Combine levels if you like

```
d.unstack().swaplevel(0, 1, 1).sort_index(1).loc[:, lambda x: x.gt(0).any()].pipe(
    lambda x: x.set_axis([f'{a}_{b}' for a, b in x.columns], axis=1, inplace=False)
)

       cat1_A  cat1_D  cat1_E  cat2_B  cat2_F
user                                         
12345       1       1       0       1       1
34567       0       0       1       0       1
67890       0       1       1       0       2
```

Comment: This works, but it bowed my brain haha. Its so complex, and I just started with Python not long back. Thank you for answering though :)

Answer (score 2):

with `pd.get_dummies` then `multiply` and `groupby`

```
(pd.get_dummies(df[['cat1', 'cat2']])
   .multiply(df.views, axis=0)
   .groupby(df.user).sum()
)
```

Output:

```
       cat1_A  cat1_D  cat1_E  cat2_B  cat2_F
user                                         
12345       1       1       0       1       1
34567       0       0       2       0       2
67890       0       1       1       0       2
```